# How to merge large dataframe on join and eliminate non-relevant columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dask

Given a dataframe where the first column is linked to the 3rd and the 5th and the 2nd is linked to the 4th and sixth. The columns are:

- **SRC ID**:  Unique index to the `SRC` column
- **TRG ID**:  Unique index to the `TRG` column
- **SRC LANG**: The language of the `SRC` column
- **TRG LANG**: The language of the `TRG` column
- **SRC**: The text in the language specified by `SRC LANG`
- **TRG**: The text in the language specified by `TRG LANG`

Note: `SRC` and `TRG` are translations of each other.

In code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

instr = """SRC ID   TRG ID  SRC LANG    TRG LANG    SRC TRG
8366    170897  fra jpn C'est sec comme la poussière.   砂をかむように味気ないね。
8366    243583  fra eng C'est sec comme la poussière.   It's dry as dust.
8366    1840509 fra epo C'est sec comme la poussière.   Estas seke, kiel polvo.
8366    4401595 fra tur C'est sec comme la poussière.   Toz kadar kuru.
1   77  cmn deu 我們試試看！  Lass uns etwas versuchen!
1   1276    cmn eng 我們試試看！  Let's try something.
1   2481    cmn spa 我們試試看！  ¡Intentemos algo!
1   5350    cmn kor 我們試試看！  뭔가 해보자!
1   344899  cmn jpn 我們試試看！  やってみましょう。
1   345549  cmn cmn 我們試試看！  试一下吧。
"""
pd.read_csv(StringIO(instr), sep='\t')
```

[out]:

```
SRC ID  TRG ID  SRC LANG    TRG LANG    SRC TRG
0   8366    170897  fra jpn C'est sec comme la poussière.   砂をかむように味気ないね。
1   8366    243583  fra eng C'est sec comme la poussière.   It's dry as dust.
2   8366    1840509 fra epo C'est sec comme la poussière.   Estas seke, kiel polvo.
3   8366    4401595 fra tur C'est sec comme la poussière.   Toz kadar kuru.
4   1   77  cmn deu 我們試試看！  Lass uns etwas versuchen!
5   1   1276    cmn eng 我們試試看！  Let's try something.
6   1   2481    cmn spa 我們試試看！  ¡Intentemos algo!
7   1   5350    cmn kor 我們試試看！  뭔가 해보자!
8   1   344899  cmn jpn 我們試試看！  やってみましょう。
9   1   345549  cmn cmn 我們試試看！  试一下吧。
```

Given the dataframe as such, if we want to extract the English-Japanese translation, **how could I pivot through the SRC column from the TRG column to get this desired output?**

```
170897  243583  eng jpn It's dry as dust    砂をかむように味気ないね。
1276    344899  eng jpn Let's try something.    やってみましょう。
```

I've tried this:

```
jpn = df[df['TRG LANG'] == 'jpn']
eng = df[df['TRG LANG'] == 'eng']
df2 = pd.merge(right=eng, left=jpn, on='SRC ID')[['TRG ID_x', 'TRG ID_y', 'TRG_x', 'TRG_y']].dropna()
```

But it's a little inefficient since I've to loop through the whole dataset twice to create jpn and eng separatedly.

The whole data set has at least 12,000,000+ rows.

**Is there a better way to do this?** What are the alternative `dask`, `pandas` or other dataframe solutions?

One nice assumption that one can make is that the `SRC ID` are in running numbers and the dataframe order is sorted by `SRC ID`.

Comment: One idea I could think of, separate your dataframe according to src id. Then run multi-thread to join each group. i.e. src id 1-10000 group1, src id 10001-20000 group2. Run multi-threading for each group and then concat results. Not sure whether it is possible to have hadoop spark infrastructure support, if yes, I will use DataFrame in Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `set_index` with `drop=False` in order to keep `'TRG LANG'` in the dataframe proper as well as being able to use as both a means to filter with `loc` and `unstack`

```
trg_langs = ['eng', 'jpn']
trg = ['TRG ID', 'TRG LANG', 'TRG']
df.set_index('TRG LANG', drop=False).loc[trg_langs] \
  .set_index('SRC ID', append=True)[trg].unstack(0)

          TRG ID         TRG LANG                        TRG               
TRG LANG     eng     jpn      eng  jpn                   eng            jpn
SRC ID                                                                     
1           1276  344899      eng  jpn  Let's try something.      やってみましょう。
8366      243583  170897      eng  jpn     It's dry as dust.  砂をかむように味気ないね。
```

---

**Option 2**
You can use `groupby.cumcount` to create a unique index then `unstack`

```
d1 = df.loc[
    df['TRG LANG'].isin(['eng', 'jpn']),
    ['SRC ID', 'TRG ID', 'TRG LANG', 'TRG']
].sort_values(['SRC ID', 'TRG LANG'])

d1.set_index(['SRC ID', d1.groupby('SRC ID').cumcount()]).unstack()

        TRG ID         TRG LANG                        TRG               
             0       1        0    1                     0              1
SRC ID                                                                   
1         1276  344899      eng  jpn  Let's try something.      やってみましょう。
8366    243583  170897      eng  jpn     It's dry as dust.  砂をかむように味気ないね。
```